# Android: как изменить линию одного итема в ListView?

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить ширину и цвет линии одного итема в списке?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip" <!-- ширина -->
        android:background="@color/dark_grey" <!-- цвет -->
        />
```

Цвет надо задавать в файле values/colors.xml типа:

```
<resources>
    <color name="black">#00000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="sky_blue">#87CEFA</color>
    <color name="light_blue">#A9D0F5</color>
    <color name="light_yellow">#F2F5A9</color>
    <color name="light_magenta">#DA81F5</color>
    <color name="dark_grey">#AAA</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#00008B</color>
    <color name="light_grey">#D3D3D3</color>
</resources>
```